# MySQL table managment

Tags: mysql

I want to build an online shopping system with 4000 products. Each produtcs have at least 3 photos, but some products have only 3, other products have maximum 10. (avg 7)

Which is the best practice? And why?

1. I create a table, where I set id, product id and 10 colums for images and I will manage 1 row/product (~12 colums and 4000 rows).
2. I create a table, where I can store only id, 1 column for image  (~3 colums and 28.000 rows)

I think, the 2nd version is better write- and readable with PHP, but I am afraid of too many rows.

I know that MySQL can manage 1 million rows too, but this is a small hosting package (~12$/year) not a full server.

Comment: are u going to store pictures as links or blob ?

Comment: I want to store the relative path and every image is unique on the website. Every image belongs to only one product,.